# Many to Many WTForms Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask

Boa noite!

Estou fazendo a implementação de um sistema com **wtforms flask**, e parei na seguinte situação: tenho CRUD produtos e um CRUD Orçamento, logo, terei items de produtos no orçamento (n:n). Nas pesquisas que realizei somente encontro exemplo de "SelectField" (combo), mas preciso de uma grid para adicionar itens de produto nesse orçamento.
Alguém teria uma orientação, exemplo ou dicas de como realizar essa implementação?
Estou com a idéia de cria uma 3 classe (ItemOrcamento), apontar as FKs (Produto e Orçamento) e tratar na codificação o CRUD de items.

Fico no aguardo, um abraço!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi que a pergunta foi feita há um tempo mas vou deixar aqui algumas sugestões.

A experiência que tive com WTForms é que ele funciona muito bem para formulários simples. Já com formulário complexos (com tabelas, conteúdo dinâmico, operações client-side - com Angular, por exemplo), eu percebi que ele se torna um limitador. As vezes você gasta muito tempo tentando sincronizar o formulário HTML com o formulário do WTForms.

Quando tenho que utilizar esses tipos de formulários mais robustos, eu utilizo alguma biblioteca client-side (**Angular**, por exemplo), crio o JSON no lado cliente e trato ele no server-side.

Uma outra alternativa é utilizar o conceito de Dynamic Form Composition ([link](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition)) que tenta prever esse tipo de construção. Mas, ao meu ver, é bem chatinho de usar =X

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: No fim acabei desistindo de fazer nesse formato, e passei para o Django com REST Framework. Com o Rest do Flask ficou mais fácil também!